# Angular injector error with minified JavaScript

Tags: angularjs, coffeescript

I have been struggling to find a solution for this problem:

I am using Angular.js on my site.

I use CoffeeScript to write my JavaScript in Visual Studios 2012. When I save my CoffeeScript -   both a  minified and un-minified version of the JavaScript file is saved.

While using any minified version of JavaScript files on  my webpage  I keep getting this error:

Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider
Unknown provider: nProvider <- n
This error results from the $injector being unable to resolve a required dependency. To fix this, make sure the dependency is defined and spelled correctly. For example:

If I don’t use the minified version everything works fine.

Here is how I use angular to declare my App in each JavaScript file

```
(function() {
  var myApp;

  myApp = angular.module("myApp", ['uploaddirective']);

  myApp.controller("videoController", function($scope, $http, $compile) {
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use array notation for minification-safe dependency injection:

```
myApp.controller("videoController", ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', function($scope, $http, $compile) {
```

Another option is to use build task to automatically annotate injections for you:

```
// @ngInject
myApp.controller("videoController", function($scope, $http, $compile) {
```

You will need grunt or gulp plugin for this, like [ngAnnotate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-annotate).

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Comment: Use Inline Array Annotation. - Auto dependency injection doesn't work with minified Javascript. See https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di

Answer (score 1):

When you minifying the above code you will get something like

```
a.controller("videoController", function(x, y, z) {...
```

note that `$scope, $http, $compile` are replaced with `x, y, z`.

So when angular starts to execute Controller can't find the injectors because `$scope, $http, $compile` are replaced with `x, y, z` and there are no inject-able providers as `x`, `y` or `z`, so angular will trigger a error saying `Unknown Provider`.

**solution 1**

you can follow [`Inline Array Annotation`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) as,

```
myApp.controller("videoController", ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', function($scope, $http, $compile) {...
```

after minifying this you will get something like

```
a.controller("videoController", ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', function(x, y, z) {...
```

minifying process doesn't effect on strings, here angular will use a array with strings that will match the providers. Here angular will match the `x` with `$scope` and so on.

**solution 2**

[`$inject Property Annotation`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)

```
var MyController = function($scope, $http, $compile) {
    // controller function ...
}

MyController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$compile'];

myApp.controller("videoController", MyController);
```

additionally check [`ng-annotate`](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate)