# angular state.go not working when minified

Tags: angularjs

We use the gulp to minify js files.

in my project i have config.js  which contains following code.

```
var routerApp = angular.module('MyApp');
routerApp.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, APPCONSTANTS, $sceProvider) {

    //$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

    $stateProvider        
        .state('myState', {
            url: '',

            templateUrl: 'SomePath' + 'index.html',            
            controller: 'myController'
        });

    $sceProvider.enabled(false);
});
routerApp.controller("myStartController", function ($state) {
    $state.go("myState");
})
```

and index.cshtml contains following code

```
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
..Contains required links
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="myStartController">@*this to call state.go*@</div>
    <div ui-view style="height: calc(100% - 64px);"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This works fine when not minified breaks otherwise. Not getting any specific error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular injector error with minified JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33057062/angular-injector-error-with-minified-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all of your registrations (`config`, `controller`, etc), use this syntax:

```
routerApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', 'APPCONSTANTS', '$sceProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, APPCONSTANTS, $sceProvider) {    
    // Your code
}]);

routerApp.controller("myStartController", ['$state', function ($state) {
    // Your code
}]);
```

This is known as the [Inline Array Annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#inline-array-annotation).

Comment: thanks, post this change getting Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/unpr?p0=rProvider%20%3C-%20r%20%3C-undefinedmyStartController

Comment: It seems that it's trying to go to `myState`, but it cannot find the `myController` which is the controller associated with that state.